# variable string has html in it and will not allow whitespace in javascript parameter

Tags: c#, html

I am writing a small script to be ran in a dialog when it opens. In the code I have a string type variable with html code, such as `string script = <a onclick=runthis('This will not work with white spaces')><a/>`. That will not work but if i take out all the white spaces it will work fine. Question is is there a way to pass in a parameter with spaces or any other way to do this? thanks for any examples or suggestions.

Small example of the error, This is a string in c#.

```
 "<div id=&quot;DialogEditPhoto&quot;  style=&quot;display: inline-block; position: relative; cursor: pointer&quot; " +
                    "onclick=EditPhoto(&quot;Wlcometo thesouth&quot;,&apos;dsaasd&apos;,&apos;" + pic.ID + "&apos;);>"
```

Comment: get rid of any line breaking white space. It should wrap with the editor, and be one long continuous string. It is pretty specific to JS

Comment: not sure i follow. This was all one line before i just made it two lines now to read better. Is that what you mean? if not can you put example

Comment: Yeah I thats what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the character encoding you're doing is a little unnecessary. You need quotes around your JS function, which is why the whitespace is causing it not to work.

```
string div = "<div id=\"DialogEditPhoto\"" + 
    " style=\"display: inline-block; position: relative; cursor: pointer\"" + 
    " onclick=\"EditPhoto('Wlcometo thesouth','dsaasd','" + pic.ID + "');\">" + 
    "</div>"
```

And before you sent it to the client, let .NET do the character encoding for you:

```
string encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(div);
```

Also, you didn't close your opening `<div>` tag; I'm not sure if you were intending to, but I added it anyway.

Comment: Thank you that was the problem, not sure why i did not catch that

Answer (score 0):

`"<div id=&quot;DialogEditPhoto&quot;  style=&quot;display: inline-block; position: relative; cursor: pointer&quot; " +"onclick=EditPhoto(&quot;Wlcometo thesouth&quot;,&apos;dsaasd&apos;,&apos;" + pic.ID + "&apos;);>"`

^^Copy and Paste That

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript string literals *can not* contain a literal newline character**.

There are actually 4 characters in the "LineTerminator" class which *can not* appear in a string literal directly: LF/Line Feed, CR/Carriage Return, LS/Line Separator and PS/Paragraph Separator. More information can be found in section 7.8.4: String Literals and 7.2: Whitespace sections of the EMCAScript 5th Edition specification.

```
// read the error console, this is a syntax error and is reported by FF as:
//   SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
var bad = "because it
    contained a literal newline"

// this is valid syntax
var good = "because it\n\
    didn't contain one"
```

Note that in the 2nd case the last '\' (which *must* be the last character on the line) signifies that the string literal does not terminate but continues on to the next line (no character takes it's place, hence the `\n` before) to embed the newline into the string.

Happy coding.